# How to get difference in time between stored date and current date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using PHP and mysql to currently work on a project and I want to be able to automatically get the difference in time between the stored date and the current date, it can be in days,hours and minutes depending on the duration I want. So please I need a good suggestion on the best way to do this, either it be javascript or even a PHP function.

Comment: what type and timezone is your stored datetime in?  do you really mean current date, not current time?

Answer (score 0):

What about php diff date function ?

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
?>
```

You can also check at this answer [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)